# Привязать к кнопке тулбара функцию в kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo

Пытаюсь к кнопке тулбара кендовскго грида подвязать функцию. Код пишу так:

```
toolbar: [{ name: "create", text:"<span id='AddContenderButton'>Добавить претендента</span>"} ]
```

А сама функция:

```
$("#AddContenderButton").click(function () {
    alert("Нажали добавить!");
});
```

Но функция не вызывается(
Что делаю не так?

Comment: Как обычно, жду развертки вашего кода в доджо

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему. Немного топорно, но работает. Просто привязал к oncklick события функцию. Она вызывается и всё нормально обрабатывается.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#AddContenderButton").ready().on("click", function () {
    alert("Нажали добавить!");
});
```